# Storing and adding past point clouds from kinect using point cloud library and ROS

Tags: c++, kinect, openni, point-cloud-library, ros

I am trying to build a local map by adding  point clouds from Kinect using iterative closest point from Point Cloud Library and ROS Hydro in Ubuntu 12.04. However, I am not able to add consecutive point clouds together to update the map. The problem is that the aligned pointcloud is only added with the source pointcloud for those current frames. I am having a bit of trouble storing the previous point clouds. As seen from the code I update the map with

```
Final+=*cloud_in;
```

However a new Final is computed every time, so I lose the old Final value. I need to retain it. I am a novice in C++ and ROS, so I would greatly appreciate help on this matter.

Listed below is the Code:

```
ros::Publisher _pub;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_in (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

void
cloud_cb2 (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& next_input)
{
  pcl::fromROSMsg (*next_input, *cloud_in);
  //remove NAN points from the cloud
  std::vector<int> indices;
  pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(*cloud_in,*cloud_in, indices);
// Convert the sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 data to pcl::PointCloud
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud2_in (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  pcl::fromROSMsg (*next_input, *cloud2_in);
  //remove NAN points
  std::vector<int> indices2;
  pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(*cloud2_in,*cloud2_in, indices2);

  pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::PointXYZRGB> icp;
  icp.setInputSource(cloud2_in);
  icp.setInputTarget(cloud_in);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> Final;
  icp.align(Final);
  std::cout << "has converged:" << icp.hasConverged() << " score: " <<
  icp.getFitnessScore() << std::endl;
  std::cout << icp.getFinalTransformation() << std::endl;
  Final+=*cloud_in;

 // Convert the pcl::PointCloud to sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 output;
  pcl::toROSMsg( Final, output );
  // Publish the map
  _pub.publish(output);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init (argc, argv, "my_pcl_tutorial");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // ROS subscriber for /camera/depth_registered/points
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe(
                    "/camera/depth_registered/points",
                    2,
                    cloud_cb2
                    );

  // Create ROS publisher for transformed pointcloud
  _pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>(
                           "output",
                           1
                           );
  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong... I mean, the idea of cloud_cb2 is to be a callback (at least that is the common thing in the examples where they use a similar name and definition), so the idea is that every time it enters this function, it gives you a new cloud that you should integrate to your previous cloud...

I suppose that by doing `pcl::fromROSMsg (*next_input, *cloud2_in);` you are forcing the program to give you a new cloud, but it should not be like that as I told you before.

Then, to answer your question:

```
icp.align(Final);
```

If you read the tutorial from PCL [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php), it tells you that this function receives as input a point cloud variable that will contain the icp result.

Also, the result will be the alignment (or try) of

```
icp.setInputSource(cloud2_in);
```

to match

```
icp.setInputTarget(cloud_in);
```

So you are overwriting `Final`, with the 2 new clouds align, and then adding the points of `cloud_in` that is already in the pointcloud.

I recommend you, to check your workflow again, it should be something like this

```
ros::Publisher _pub;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_in (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr Final (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

void
cloud_cb2 (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& next_input)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr tmp_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  pcl::fromROSMsg (*next_input, *cloud_in);
  //remove NAN points from the cloud
  std::vector<int> indices;
  pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(*cloud_in,*cloud_in, indices);

  pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::PointXYZRGB> icp;
  icp.setInputSource(cloud_in);
  icp.setInputTarget(Final);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> Final;
  icp.align(tmp_cloud);
  std::cout << "has converged:" << icp.hasConverged() << " score: " <<
  icp.getFitnessScore() << std::endl;
  std::cout << icp.getFinalTransformation() << std::endl;
  Final = tmp_cloud;

 // Convert the pcl::PointCloud to sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 output;
  pcl::toROSMsg( Final, output );
  // Publish the map
  _pub.publish(output);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init (argc, argv, "my_pcl_tutorial");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // ROS subscriber for /camera/depth_registered/points
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe(
                    "/camera/depth_registered/points",
                    2,
                    cloud_cb2
                    );

  // Create ROS publisher for transformed pointcloud
  _pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>(
                           "output",
                           1
                           );
  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}
```

I just did some changes to show how it should be, but I haven't tested it so probably you'll need to correct it even further. I hope this answer helps you. Also, I do not know how the ICP algorithm will work in the first call back when the Final cloud is empty. Also, I recommend some downsampling of the data, or else it will use incredibly huge amounts of memory and cpu after doing it for some frames

Comment: Yes, ICP aligns the source to target. It gives the transformed source cloud. I was trying to add the transformed cloud2_in(source_cloud) and cloud_in(target_cloud) together to get the global map.I understand now I will have to add the source cloud instead.

I also agree to downsample.

Your code gave me a good starting point in saving the frames `Final=tmp_cloud`. However as you mentioned for the first iteration I would need a `Final`:I was thinking the first 2 frames then?. How would I go about grabbing the next frame when the callback can take only 1 pointcloud at a time? If statement maybe?

Comment: @asidd you can always check the amount of points in the point cloud, if it is 0, then just add as it is the new cloud, if it is not 0, do the normal procedure. Remember that you only get one cloud. To check the number of points do: `int n = Final->points.size();` and then a simple `if`. To downsample I use voxel grid from the pcl library. here is a [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/voxel_grid.php)

Comment: The points.size did the trick! In the end I did `Final+=tmp_cloud` to store the aligned pointcloud plus the target pointcloud. I have to mess with the parameters a bit to make it more robust and accurate. Downsampling by voxel filter considerably reduced computation time as well. Thank you.